# Help with OAUTH twitter post from Android

Tags: android

I want to use https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth for posting twitter status from android

But I have problem with filling this constants. Where to find

```
public static final String USER_TOKEN 
public static final String USER_SECRET 
public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN
public static final String REQUEST_SECRET
private static final Uri CALLBACK_URI
```

I create app in twitter , I guess USER_SECRET  is Consumer secret. But I don't know other values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final String USER_TOKEN 
public static final String USER_SECRET
```

User Token and User Secret are provided by Twitter when you register your application. (required to initiate the OAuth dance with Twitter).

```
public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN
public static final String REQUEST_SECRET
```

There are just 2 constants used in the sample application (used as keys) to store the actual request token and token secret you'll receive during the OAuth dance.

```
private static final Uri CALLBACK_URI
```

The callback URI defines where twitter will redirect the user after he authorizes the request. In case of a webapp, this can be a URL pointing to your application.
In case of an Android app, this can be any URI.

For example, the following activity expects a callback url to look like x-oauthflow://callback.

```
    <activity android:name=".PrepareRequestTokenActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="x-oauthflow" android:host="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more info, check this page : http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/

Comment: You can register your application (required for OAuth integration) at http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Comment: Also, different sites/apps/implementors use different terminology. 

In this case you can consider 

Consumer key = User token  and 
Consumer secret = User Secret

Comment: When registering app Application Type should be Browser  ? and Callback URL?

Comment: and how to do this "required to initiate the OAuth dance with Twitter" thanks

Comment: Sign up at dev.twitter.com and register your app to get the consumer key and consumer secret to get things started. Regarding the callback URL, if your applications is a webapp select application type=browser and specify a URL to your webapp that will capture the access token. (this needs to be developped by you).
If your application is a fat client (desktop app, mobile app, ...), just specify client instead of webapp